# File.Create not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

It might be a little funny but I am facing some stupid issue.

I am using

`File.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1")).Dispose()`

and

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(context.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1")))
```

when I using this the error is given to me is "Could not find a part of the path "

If am storing the path in a string then its working fine else producing error.

For your reference I am copying my function code snippet.

Please help

Thanks

```
Public Shared Function LogErrorToLogFile(ByVal ee As Exception, ByVal userFriendlyError As String) As String
        Try
               Dim path As String = context.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1"))
            ' check if directory exists
            If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then
                'Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(context.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1")))
            End If
            path = path & DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yy") & ".log"
            ' check if file exist
            If Not File.Exists(path) Then
                File.Create(path).Dispose()
                'File.Create(context.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1"))).Dispose()
                File.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1")).Dispose()
            End If
            ' log the error now
            Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(path)
                'Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(context.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1")))
              writer.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(vbCr & vbLf & "Log written at : " & DateTime.Now.ToString() & vbCr & vbLf & "Error occured on page : " & context.Current.Request.Url.ToString() & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf & "Here is the actual error :" & vbLf & ee.ToString()))
                writer.WriteLine("==========================================")
                writer.Flush()
                writer.Close()
            End Using
            Return userFriendlyError
        Catch
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: what is the value of LogFilePath1 in your config file?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the current lines with the comment-outed lines in your function code snippet, you're logic is changed because when you use Path, there is added a filename [dd-MMM-yy].log to the path-string. but you don't use that addition when you use the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFilePath1") directly!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have not used the folder path with slash (ex: @"C:\FolderName\") and that is the reason you are getting the error.